# js variable to css [clip-path img gallery]

Tags: javascript, css, variables, gallery, clip-path

I'm trying to make a random clip-path in each image whenever someone clicks a button.

For some reason only the first image is cut. the others remain the same.

I send the code in codepen and snipped.

https://codepen.io/fredericopimpao/pen/ZvBOwN?editors=1111

```js
var test = document.querySelector('.test')
window.setInterval(function(){

  var rand = Math.random()* (200 - 10) + 30;

  test.style.setProperty('--ola', rand+'%');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.test{
    clip-path: polygon(var(--ola) 30%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%,0% 100%);   
}
img{width:200px;}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">

<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` will return **only** the first element that match the selector, Instead you should use `document.querySelectorAll` and run a loop over all the elements.

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('.test')
window.setInterval(function() {

  var rand = Math.random() * (200 - 10) + 30;
  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
    test[i].style.setProperty('--ola', rand + '%');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.test {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--ola) 30%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">

<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
```

And if you want a **different** `clip-path` for each element, simply include the random inside the loop :

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('.test')
window.setInterval(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    var rand = Math.random() * (200 - 10) + 30;
    test[i].style.setProperty('--ola', rand + '%');
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.test {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--ola) 30%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">

<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
```

Another way is to change directly the CSS property and in this case you need to change it only once for all the element :

```js
var clip = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style;
window.setInterval(function() {

  var rand = Math.random() * (200 - 10) + 30;
  clip.setProperty('--ola', rand + '%');

}, 1000);
```

```css
.test {
  clip-path: polygon(var(--ola) 30%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">

<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
<img class="test" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Bor5lkRyeGo/hqdefault.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, and the perfect explanation.